# Error MSB6006: "lc.exe" exited with code -1073740771

Tags: compiler-errors, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting the following compile error very frequently on one of our project on .NET 4.0:

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3274,5): error MSB6006:"lc.exe" exited with code -1073740771*

Using Visual Studio in administrator mode, I already tried:

- clean up the solution and recompile
- recompile projects individually
- delete the bin and obj folders of each library and recompile
- restart Visual Studio
- restart the PC

For some reason, after numerous attempts, the problem resolved itself.
However every now and then it comes back making us waste a lot of time every time.

Thanks in advance for any advice